# SQL - multiply selected value by -1 if value is not null

Tags: sql-server

I'm selecting a value from a table and multiply it by `-1` because I need the value to be negative:

```
sv.SemVers_AnzahlProd*(-1)
```

But the value could be NULL, so I want to check somehow if the value is `NULL`. If it is, don't multiply it by `-1`.

How can I achieve this? I check if `ISNULL()` is suitable for this problem, but it's not because I need to multiply the value by -1 is the value is NOT `NULL`.

Comment: NULL times anything is still NULL!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to do anything:

```
SELECT -1 * NULL
```

returns a value of `NULL`